# Servo Motor Controlled by an iOS device app

Tags: ios, database, arduino

I'm trying to run a servo motor that supposed to receive data from an iPad app. Assume this servo motor is going to be used to commercially and can't use a computer to run the program. I have to use a processor that is pre programmed and use an normal power supply. The servo motor must be controlled wirelessly by an iPad device. The app can send data to the motor directly or use a server. I'm wondering what would be the possible ways for the servo motor to read the data from the server or from the iPad? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for something similar to this a project that I have been working on.  It is on Android, but should at least provide a framework for what you're trying to accomplish.

### Basic Communication:

```na
[Android/IPad] <---Wifi (UDP)---> [WIFI Reciever] <---Serial ---> [Arduino]--->[Servo]
```

For a Wifi receiver, I am currently using a Linux laptop.  I plan on moving to an OpenWRT access point in the near future though.

### My Project

- [Power-Wheelino](http://code.google.com/p/power-wheelino/)

Comment: the servo motor is connected to a arduino and an external power supply. This arduino should either communicate directly with the iPad using bonjour or some server. I'm thinking of eliminating the laptop that u were using. any suggestion?

Comment: You could use an Ethernet shield for the Arduino.  That may work, but you'd still need a Wifi Access point.  A wireless router would be perfect for this because it obviously provides a wireless connection and you can use the onboard serial connection.  I'm in the process of cross compiling for the WRT-54G v2 router running OpenWRT.  Unless you can find a wireless shield (not zigbee) I think a wifi router is the way to go.  You can power the Arduino directly from the AP's power brick as well so.., one power supply and direct communication = win!

Answer (score 0):

Your question in very vague is a bit confusing with conflicting information.

"...app can send data to the motor directly" and "...servo motor to read the data from the server or from the iPad?" So which is it? Motor reads from iPad or iPad sends signal to motor? While many pieces are capable of either push or pull methods of getting data, it makes the question very open ended and realistically, it would probably be difficult for a component to reliably connect to and pull information down from an iPad.

Either way all controllable mechanics have a defined and documented way to communicate. Without exact specifics (and probably even with them), the best information is to read the documentation for your servo motor or contact the manufacturer.